# How to change z-index of chart js tooltip?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, tooltip, chart.js

I have 4 charts placed side by side using bootstrap's grid system. One of the chart's width is just one col wide (col-md-1), which uses bubble chart(simply shows circles from top to bottom). However, when I hover on the bubble, the tooltip gets truncated. I tried to change z-index of the div inside which the chart element is placed, but that did not solve the problem.

This is how it shows up on mouse over:
[image]

Kindly let me know how can I change the z-index of the tooltip element.

**Update**:
I have created a fiddle if that helps:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfcfsezz/1/)

Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
                col 5
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                <div style="height: 60vh;">
                    <canvas id="can" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                col 6
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can we see the css code for your tooltip?  Where are you placing it in your markup?

Comment: There is no css yet for the tooltip. I am yet to create it. But I can't figure out the target element or its class, so that i can modify it.

Comment: css is not used for styling chart.js tooltips, please see my answer below

Comment: Have you solve this problem? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: Shepherd, I had to go with Chartjs plugin. This may help you: https://jsfiddle.net/patrickactivatr/ytLtmLgs/2/

Comment: @Deepak, thanks a lot, this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not used for styling tooltips in chart.js, so you can't change the z-index.

I recommend you read the documentation on styling the tooltip at http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

To solve your problem you will have to increase the size of the container with that chart's canvas. In your fiddle, this means increasing the width of `div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"`.